# Multiplying the elements of a basis by a nonsingular matrix gives another basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $v_1$, $v_2 , \dots , v_n$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, I need to prove that the multiplication of these vectors by a nonsingular matrix also form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, $Av_1,\dots,  Av_n$).

I understand this if we had $v_1$ in the form of $(1,0,0,..0)$, $v_2$ in the form of $(0,1,0,0...)$, because then   $Av_1,\dots,  Av_n$ are the columns of $A$, and those are known to form a basis. But I am having trouble in figuring out a proof for the general case. Can someone help?

Comment: What do you know about non-singular matrices?

Comment: Hint: a non-singular matrix can be regarded as a linear transformation whose kernel is $\left \{ 0 \right \}$

Comment: Does a nonsingular matrix have an inverse?

Comment: Consider $k_1Av_1 + \cdots + k_nAv_n = 0$.  Does the fact that $A$ is nonsingular (and thus invertible) help you simplify this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take {$v_1,..., v_n$} a basis for $R^n$. we know that first, they are linearly independent and second, they span $R^n$.

now consider ${Av_1,...,Av_n}$. Suppose $\alpha_1 Av_1+...+\alpha_n Av_n = 0$, then $A(\alpha_1 v_1+...+\alpha_n v_n) = 0$. Since $A$ is invertible, we get that $\alpha_1 v_1+...+\alpha_n v_n=0$, which since {$v_1,..., v_n$} is linearly independent, we know that $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ has to be all zero. Thus {$Av_1,...,Av_n$} is linearly independent.

Take any vector $u$ in $R^n$. since{$v_1,..., v_n$} spans $R^n$,  $A^{-1}u = \alpha_1 v_1+...+\alpha_n v_n$ for some $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, so $u = \alpha_1 Av_1+...+\alpha_n Av_n$. Thus {$Av_1,...,Av_n$} spans $R^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered the question.